# No firmware update with fwupdmgr

Tags: linux, bios, updates, kde, firmware

I am trying to update my Lenovo Thinkpad T480s' firmware with `fwupdmgr` on KDE neon 5.18, but it does not update the firmware on reboot.

```
root@mymachine:~# fwupdmgr --version
client version: 1.0.9
daemon version: 1.0.9
compile-time dependency versions
        appstream-glib: 0.7.7
        gusb:   0.2.11
        fwupdate:       10
        efivar: 34
root@mymachine:~# fwupdmgr refresh
Fetching metadata https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz
Downloading…           [***************************************]
Fetching signature https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc

root@mymachine:~# fwupdmgr update
Downloading 184.70.3626 for UEFI Device Firmware...
Updating 184.70.3626 on UEFI Device Firmware...
Decompressing…         [***************************************]
Authenticating…        [***************************************]
Scheduling…            [***************************************]
No upgrades for UEFI Device Firmware, current is 0.1.19: 0.1.19=same, 0.1.18=older, 0.1.17=older, 0.1.16=older, 0.1.13=older
No upgrades for 20L8S02D00 System Firmware, current is 0.1.37: 0.1.36=older, 0.1.34=older, 0.1.33=older, 0.1.31=older, 0.1.30=older

An update requires a reboot to complete. Restart now? [Y|n]: n
```

When I reboot, nothing happens (except that it boots into my graphical system as always). I have disabled any and all BIOS and power-on passwords.

I should add that I recently successfully updated the BIOS from a bootable USB drive, so it's not that I'm sitting on some ancient firmware version to start with.

I'm surely missing something, but what?